# Does liftA2 preserve associativity?

Tags: haskell, applicative, semigroup

Given an operation `(??)` such that

```
(a ?? b) ?? c = a ?? (b ?? c)
```

(that is to say `(??)` is associative)

must it be the case that

```
liftA2 (??) (liftA2 (??) a b) c = liftA2 (??) a (liftA2 (??) b c)
```

(that is to say that `liftA2 (??)` is associative)

If we would prefere we can rewrite this as:

```
fmap (??) (fmap (??) a <*> b) <*> c = fmap (??) a <*> (fmap (??) b <*> c)
```

---

I spent a little while staring at the applicative laws but I couldn't come up with a proof that this would be the case.  So I set out to disprove it.  All the out-of-the-box applicatives (`Maybe`, `[]`, `Either`, etc.) that I have tried, follow the law, so I thought I would create my own.

My best idea was to make a vacuous applicative with an extra piece of information attached.

```
data Vacuous a = Vac Alg
```

Where `Alg` would be some algebra I would define at my own convenience later as to make the property fail but the applicative laws succeed.

Now we define our instances as such:

```
instance Functor Vacuous where
  fmap f = id

instance Applicative Vacuous where
  pure x = Vac i
  liftA2 f (Vac a) (Vac b) = Vac (comb a b)
  (Vac a) <*> (Vac b) = Vac (comb a b)
```

Where `i` is some element of `Alg` to be determined and `comb` is a binary combinator on `Alg` also to be determined.  There is not really another way we can go about defining this.

If we want to fulfill the **Identiy** law this forces `i` to be an idenity over `comb`.  We then get **Homomorphism** and **Interchange** for free.  But now **Composition** forces `comb` to be associative over `Alg`

```
((pure (.) <*> Vac u) <*> Vac v) <*> Vac w = Vac u <*> (Vac v <*> Vac w)
   ((Vac i <*> Vac u) <*> Vac v) <*> Vac w = Vac u <*> (Vac v <*> Vac w)
               (Vac u <*> Vac v) <*> Vac w = Vac u <*> (Vac v <*> Vac w)
                (Vac (comb u v)) <*> Vac w = Vac u <*> (Vac (comb v w))
                   Vac (comb (comb u v) w) = Vac (comb u (comb v w))
                         comb (comb u v) w = comb u (comb v w)
```

Forcing us to satisfy the property.

Is there a counter example?  If not how can we prove this property?

Comment: Note that `base`'s [`instance (Applicative f, Semigroup a) => Semigroup (Ap f a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap) relies on this property being true.

Answer (score 5):

We start by rewriting the left hand side, using the applicative laws. Recall that both `<$>` and `<*>` are left-associative, so that we have, e.g., `x <*> y <*> z = (x <*> y) <*> z` and `x <$> y <*> z = (x <$> y) <*> z`.

```
(??) <$> ((??) <$> a <*> b) <*> c
= fmap/pure law
pure (??) <*> (pure (??) <*> a <*> b) <*> c
= composition law
pure (.) <*> pure (??) <*> (pure (??) <*> a) <*> b <*> c
= homomorphism law
pure ((.) (??)) <*> (pure (??) <*> a) <*> b <*> c
= composition law
pure (.) <*> pure ((.) (??)) <*> pure (??) <*> a <*> b <*> c
= homomorphism law
pure ((.) ((.) (??)) (??)) <*> a <*> b <*> c
= definition (.)
pure (\x -> (.) (??) ((??) x)) <*> a <*> b <*> c
= definition (.), eta expansion
pure (\x y z -> (??) ((??) x y) z) <*> a <*> b <*> c
= associativity (??)
pure (\x y z -> x ?? y ?? z) <*> a <*> b <*> c
```

The last form reveals that, essentially, the original expression "runs" the actions `a`, `b`, and `c` in that order, sequencing their effects in that way, and then uses `(??)` to purely combine the three results.

We can then prove that the right hand side is equivalent to the above form.

```
(??) <$> a <*> ((??) <$> b <*> c)
= fmap/pure law
pure (??) <*> a <*> (pure (??) <*> b <*> c)
= composition law
pure (.) <*> (pure (??) <*> a) <*> (pure (??) <*> b) <*> c
= composition law
pure (.) <*> pure (.) <*> pure (??) <*> a <*> (pure (??) <*> b) <*> c
= homomorphism law
pure ((.) (.) (??)) <*> a <*> (pure (??) <*> b) <*> c
= composition law
pure (.) <*> (pure ((.) (.) (??)) <*> a) <*> pure (??) <*> b <*> c
= composition law
pure (.) <*> pure (.) <*> pure ((.) (.) (??)) <*> a <*> pure (??) <*> b <*> c
= homomorphism law
pure ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??))) <*> a <*> pure (??) <*> b <*> c
= interchange law
pure ($ (??)) <*> (pure ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??))) <*> a) <*> b <*> c
= composition law
pure (.) <*> pure ($ (??)) <*> pure ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??))) <*> a <*> b <*> c
= homomorphism law
pure ((.) ($ (??)) ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??)))) <*> a <*> b <*> c
```

Now, we only have to rewrite the point-free term `((.) ($ (??)) ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??))))` in a more readable point-ful form, so that we can make it equal to the term we got in the first half of the proof. This is just a matter of applying `(.)` and `($)` as needed.

```
((.) ($ (??)) ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??))))
= \x -> (.) ($ (??)) ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??))) x
= \x -> ($ (??)) ((.) (.) ((.) (.) (??)) x)
= \x -> (.) (.) ((.) (.) (??)) x (??)
= \x y -> (.) ((.) (.) (??) x) (??) y
= \x y -> (.) (.) (??) x ((??) y)
= \x y z -> (.) ((??) x) ((??) y) z
= \x y z -> (??) x ((??) y z)
= \x y z -> x ?? y ?? z
```

where in the last step we exploited the associativity of `(??)`.

(Whew.)

Comment: Whew indeed! I find that Haskell's curried style really isn't too benefitial for that kind of proofwork.

Answer (score 4):

Not only does it preserve associativity, I would say that's perhaps *the main idea* behind the applicative laws in the first place!

Recall the maths-style form of the class:

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  funit ::    ()     -> f  ()
  fzip :: (f a, f b) -> f (a,b)
```

with laws

```
zAssc:  fzip (fzip (x,y), z) ≅ fzip (x, fzip (y,z))  -- modulo tuple re-bracketing
fComm:  fzip (fmap fx x, fmap fy y) ≡ fmap (fx***fy) (fzip (x,y))
fIdnt:  fmap id ≡ id                    -- ─╮
fCmpo:  fmap f . fmap g ≡ fmap (f . g)  -- ─┴ functor laws
```

In this approach, `liftA2` factors into fmapping a tuple-valued function over an already ready-zipped pair:

```
liftZ2 :: ((a,b)->c) -> (f a,f b) -> f c
liftZ2 f = fmap f . fzip
```

i.e.

```
liftZ2 f (a,b) = f <$> fzip (a,b)
```

Now say we have given

```
g :: (G,G) -> G
gAssc:  g (g (α,β), γ) ≡ g (α, g (β,γ))
```

or point-free (again ignoring tuple-bracket interchange)

```
gAssc:  g . (g***id) ≅ g . (id***g)
```

If we write everything in this style, it's easy to see that associativity-preservation is basically just `zAssc`, with everything about `g` happening in a separate `fmap` step:

```
liftZ2 g (liftZ2 g (a,b), c)
    {-liftA2'-} ≡ g <$> fzip (g <$> fzip (a,b), c)
{-fIdnt,fComm-} ≡ g . (g***id) <$> fzip (fzip (a,b), c)
{-gAssc,zAssc-} ≡ g . (id***g) <$> fzip (a, fzip (b,c))
{-fComm,fIdnt-} ≡ g <$> fzip (a, g <$> fzip (b,c))
    {-liftA2'-} ≡ liftZ2 g (a, liftZ2 g (b,c))
```

Comment: Indeed -- whenever one has to prove something with the applicative laws, using the monoidal presentation is a sensible default.